# How to render/resolve react-router enpoints when being served from an express/node server

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, react-router

I am using react-router in a react frontend app that is served from a directory, "/build",
of my express server. All the non-frontend functionality (database etc.) come from an endpoint "localhost:3003/api/something" and I have the frontend setup to serve from "localhost:3003/".

The problem I have is that when I navigate from the frontend's home ("localhost:3003/") to elsewhere, e.g. "localhost:3003/drinks/1", everything works fine. However, when I reload the browser whilst at "localhost:3003/drinks/1" or navigate directly to that URL, it gives an "endpoint not found" error.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add those routes on the server side.

A simple way for an SPA to handle every route is like this:

```js
app.get('*', handler);
```

Answer (score 0):

This error is because react-router is using history.pushState() to resolve the endpoint but if you reload the server will attempt to serve you that endpoint from the server, and that endpoint doesn't exist to the server.
There is a way to tell the server to defer this render to react-router.

```
app.get('/drinks/*', function response(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html'));
});
```

Now  index.js will serve any request that goes to localhost:3003/drinks/anything. Meaning, the front-end will be rendered accordingly by react-router instead of being hijacked by express.